# How to publish the Jar file into jfrog as a new version instead of deleting/overwriting the pervious one

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, build.gradle, artifactory

I am trying to publish the jar file into jfrog. At first it works fine. But when I tried to deploy an artifact under the same path more than once, changing the application version as 2.0.0(before it was 1.0.0), it gives me this error.

> "message" : "Not enough permissions to delete/overwrite artifact 'customer-service:customer-service/com/customer/service/core/1.0.0/customer_ervice_core-1.0.0.jar' (user: 'username' needs DELETE permission)."

This is how my build.gradle file looks like.

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

buildscript {
   repositories {
      jcenter()

   }
   dependencies {
      //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
      classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
   }
}

plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5' apply false
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
   id 'java'
   id 'maven-publish'
   id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '4.28.1'
}

allprojects {
   apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
   apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
   publications {
      mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
         artifactId = 'customer_service_core'
         from components.java

         pom {
            name = 'Customer service core module'
            description = 'Customer service core module'
         }
      }
   }
}

artifactory {
   contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"

   jar {
      enabled = true
   }

   publish {
      repository {
         repoKey = 'customer-service'
         username = "${artifactory_user}"
         password = "${artifactory_password}"
         maven = true
      }
      defaults {
         // Reference to Gradle publications defined in the build script.
         // This is how we tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be
         // published to Artifactory.
         publications('mavenJava')
         publishArtifacts = true
         // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts.
         properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
         // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
         publishPom = true
      }
   }
}

group = 'com.customer.service'
version = '2.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
   imports {
      mavenBom SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

   // lombok dependencies
   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
   annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I want to know is there any way to deploy our jar files as a new version without overwriting the pervious one? Do I always need to include a version number manually in the path to be deployed, if so how can I do it though this build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

I think snapshot Repo maybe the solution and you can save many different versions as you like.

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-does-the-max-unique-snapshots-parameter-work-in-artifactory/